# 9 patch-image strange behaviour in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

As It was suggested in [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780178/listview-items-background-with-gradient-in-fragment) I have to use 9-patch image with gradient for listview item background.

But when I use 9-patch image, there are still problems with gradients:

[image]

9-patch, test.9.png:

[image]

But when I left transperent line 1 px height between gradient and bottom 9-patch line, that responds for horizontal content placement it's all ok, and I have good looking gradients.

9-patch image:

[image]

And closer to see transperent line:

[image]

And it's a result:

[image]

**I've got good looking gradients, but there are transparent lines, that I don't need. On the image you can see black background behind list because of this line. How to draw 9-patch image in order to have good gradients and don't have "holes" in background?**

I'm using actionbarsherlock for fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Draw9patch images doesn't work well with gradients you will find some diferences displaying it in several Android OS so don´t use it.

Use a [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

[Changing gradient background colors on Android at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941606/changing-gradient-background-colors-on-android-at-runtime)

[Creating Nine (9) Patch png files with Gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140749/creating-nine-9-patch-png-files-with-gradients)

Comment: GradientDrawable still looks bad. Any other solution?